# How to access values from stdClass in php

Tags: php, stdclass

print_r($result); prints the below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [insertCount] => 0
            [updateCount] => 1
            [rejectedCount] => 0
            [totalCount] => 1
            [errorMessage] => 
        )

)
```

How can I get the values of insertCount, updateCount, rejectedCount, totalCount and errorMessage from the $result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var_dump($result->result->insertCount);
var_dump($result->result->updateCount);
var_dump($result->result->rejectedCount);
var_dump($result->result->totalCount);
var_dump($result->result->errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `print_r($result)` gives the output you have pasted, simply use:

```
$result->result->insertCount
```

Comment: This works too, but I can only give one accepted answer.